# Javascript convert Datetime to Time

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

Is it possible to get the time from the following datetime in javascript?

```
 2014-11-24 08:30:00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Found the solution to my problem in the duplicate:

```
 datetime.substr(11, 5);
 //returns 08:30
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: use moment.js(http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

What about `slice`? It should be the fastest when you know you always get datetime (and time is in last 8 chars).

```
var datetime = "2014-11-24 08:30:00";
var time = datetime.slice(-8);

alert(time); // returns "08:30:00"
```

Answer (score -3):

```
new Date("2014-11-24 08:30:00").getTime();
```

This code block will get time from your exact date.

Comment: Depending on what the questioner means by *get the time*, this may not answer the question. `getTime()` does not extract the time part of a Date object, it converts that object into the number of milliseconds elapsed since the epoch instead.

Comment: You are right, but question is clear for my situation. Otherwise he must specify the hour or day as a time meaning.